# How do I find the index of an element in a list in Racket?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

This is trivial implement of course, but I feel there is certainly something built in to Racket that does this. Am I correct in that intuition, and if so, what is the function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Strangely, there isn't a built-in procedure in Racket for finding the 0-based index of an element in a list (the opposite procedure *does* exist, it's called [`list-ref`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list-index#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list-ref%29%29)). However, it's not hard to implement efficiently:

```
(define (index-of lst ele)
  (let loop ((lst lst)
             (idx 0))
    (cond ((empty? lst) #f)
          ((equal? (first lst) ele) idx)
          (else (loop (rest lst) (add1 idx))))))
```

But there *is* a similar procedure in `srfi/1`, it's called [`list-index`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#list-index) and you can get the desired effect by passing the right parameters:

```
(require srfi/1)

(list-index (curry equal? 3) '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> 2

(list-index (curry equal? 6) '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> #f
```

**UPDATE**

As of Racket 6.7, [`index-of`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=index-of#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._index-of%29%29) is now part of the standard library. Enjoy!

Comment: How bizarre. Would the racket-dev mailing list be the appropriate outlet for recommending this feature to be added to the language?

Comment: I guess ... but it's not a big deal given that it's so simple to implement.

Comment: @Maxwell I had forgotten about `list-index`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I am going to use that, you are amazing.

Comment: You're the first non-Racket-dev I know who uses `curry`, congrats. :-) (I usually tend to use `cut` for similar situations, where true currying isn't required, because you can insert arguments in the middle, like [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/guile.git/commit/?h=stable-2.0&id=b6e374e535597448cb09588300d76b5d270d5d3a).)

Comment: Note that `acc` is a pretty bad name here, since it doesn't really accumulate anything.

Comment: @EliBarzilay agreed, fixed it!

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Well, I'd have some other stylistic comments on your code, like the use of round parens, and the related newline in the `let` bindings, but I usually keep them to myself...

Comment: @EliBarzilay I know, but old habits die hard

Comment: Why would you use list-index instead of car (filter ...)?

Comment: @raffomania because `filter` returns a list of elements, we're interested in a single element. And besides, there's no way to specify an _index_ to be returned when using `filter`. Simply put, it's not the right tool for the job

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Maybe [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html) is a better link for `cut`.

Comment: @Fabien The intent was to present a real use case for `cut`, which involved linking to real code that used it. It wasn't to provide documentation for people who didn't already know what `cut` was.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I would suggest you to swap the two halves of your answer, for quick readers like me who stop reading before the end. I think the most important information is that there is a procedure.

Comment: @Fabien I disagree. I think the most important information (wrt this answer) for a programmer to know is that he/she should feel empowered by their language to implement any procedure they feel is missing. If you later come to learn that a built-in procedure exists, you can use it in new programs and/or refactor old programs. Stopping to task the internet every time you need a basic procedure is only short-cutting yourself.

Comment: As of Racket 6.7 `index-of` is now part of the standard library! This might be worthy of an edit (although this answer works perfectly fine).

Comment: @ÓscarLópez thank you! I'm learning racket and your SO posts have been indispensable so far

Answer (score 8):

Here's a very simple implementation:

```
(define (index-of l x)
  (for/or ([y l] [i (in-naturals)] #:when (equal? x y)) i))
```

And yes, something like this should be added to the standard library, but it's just a little tricky to do so nobody got there yet.

Note, however, that it's a feature that is very rarely useful -- since lists are usually taken as a sequence that is deconstructed using only the first/rest idiom rather than directly accessing elements.  More than that, if you have a use for it and you're a newbie, then my first guess will be that you're misusing lists.  Given that, the addition of such a function is likely to trip such newbies by making it more accessible.  (But it will still be added, eventually.)

Answer (score 3):

One can also use a built-in function '`member`' which gives a sublist starting with the required item or `#f` if item does not exist in the list. Following compares the lengths of original list and the sublist returned by member:

```
(define (indexof n l)
  (define sl (member n l))
  (if sl 
      (- (length l)
         (length sl))
      #f))
```

For many situations, one may want indexes of all occurrences of item in the list. One can get a list of all indexes as follows:

```
(define (indexes_of1 x l)
  (let loop ((l l)
             (ol '())
             (idx 0))
    (cond
      [(empty? l) (reverse ol)]
      [(equal? (first l) x)
       (loop (rest l)
             (cons idx ol)
             (add1 idx))]
      [else
       (loop (rest l)
             ol
             (add1 idx))])))
```

`For/list` can also be used for this:

```
(define (indexes_of2 x l)
  (for/list ((i l)
             (n (in-naturals))
             #:when (equal? i x))
    n))
```

Testing:

```
(indexes_of1 'a '(a b c a d e a f g))
(indexes_of2 'a '(a b c a d e a f g))
```

Output:

```
'(0 3 6)
'(0 3 6)
```

Comment: Please please don't do the `-1` thing to signal that there is no index. It's much clearer and easier if you return `#false` in those cases, so that's the idiomatic way to do it