# error in position function in Lisp

Tags: lisp, racket

If I have a list like this

(1 2 3)
And I want to find the index of 2,I used the function

```
 (position '3 '(1 2 3))
```

when compiling this error was occurred

. . position: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to find the index of an element in a list. I haven't found a build-in procedure for this, but you can do this easily yourself:

```
(define (position elt lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (i 0))
    (cond
      ((null? lst) #f)
      ((eq? elt (car lst)) i)
      (else (loop (cdr lst) (+ 1 i))))))
```

then

```
(display (position '3 '(1 2 3)))
=> 2
```

Comment: @Alaa'Agha The accepted answer to [How do I find the index of an element in a list in Racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15871042/1281433) mentions that there's no such built in function in Racket, but that there are some similar functions in some of the SRFIs that are very close.